# Connecting objects with the new Open Graph

Tags: object, connection, feed

I am building a small structure of objects for my website using the (new) beta version of Open Graph. I created an object "City" and another object "Museum". Well, but Museums are usually located in cities. Is there anyway that I can implement that connection using the Open Graph?. Basically I want Facebook newsfeed to show:

"John visited **El Prado Museum** in **Madrid** using **MyApp**"

rather than

"John visited **El Prado Museum** using **MyApp**"

THANKS!!!

Diego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model this in your object by adding a custom 'city' property to your museum object, and make this point to a URL which represents a City object in your app.

However, this city property will only appear alongside where the Museum object is displayed in full i.e. in the Body of the stream story. It won't yet appear in headline i.e. "user visited museum in city" - only "User visited Museum" will appear.

[image]

FYI, you can also tag places and other people in your actions. Lets say you modelled exhibitions rather than museums - you could then post an action which would have a headline like:

```
{user} {verbed} {object} at {facebook place} with {friends} via {appname}
```

The verb would be 'visited', the object would be an exhibition object, the place would be the Facebook Place which represents the museum, and the friends would be a list of UIDs the user said they were with.

Comment: Says the guy who built the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)! +1 :-)